# cURL issue in php

Tags: php, curl

```
 $curl = curl_init($service_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

I am working with php codeigniter and I call a web service using this code. I also change the curl in php.ini and php version and add the dll files too. But when I try run this code it gives me an error that curl_init is not found.  Can anybody help me with this?

This is the error

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\2\Login\application\controllers\test101.php on line 45

Comment: The cURL extension isn't loaded for some reason.  Check the output of `phpinfo()` and verify.

Comment: <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> What version of PHP are you running? `curl_init` --> PHP 4 >= 4.0.2, PHP 5 [http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

Comment: i use php 5.4.3  this is the erro i getting SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\2\Login\application\controllers\test101.php on line 45

Comment: Same answer: cURL isn't loaded. See [PHP: cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for installation details.

Comment: I think you should be able to do `var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));` to make sure whether the extension is loaded or not

Comment: i did it everything but its not working i dont know whats happen other lib functions are working fine this one not working is there a another way to call a web services in php i calling fro java web service which accept a json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer i had to remove my php and use a old php version and now its working fine if some one need the php vertion